# HTTP 500, el codigo PHP no es capaz de ser ejecutado

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy creando un código de formulario con un `POST` con animo de aprender, el formulario esta funcionando correctamente pero una vez los datos se han pasado al `POST` el código PHP no llega a ejecutarse dando un error 500. He hecho un par de pruebas mediante echos y el código funciona bien hasta la inserción en el `mysql`.

### REQUIRED

```
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db;charset=utf8', 'root', 'pass');
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
        die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
}
```

### CODIGO

```
<?php
require_once('required/bdd.php');


session_start();





if (isset($_POST['empresa']) && isset($_POST['per_contacto']) && isset($_POST['tel_contacto']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['hor_disp_inicio']) && isset($_POST['hor_disp_final']) 
    && isset($_POST['numero_serie']) && isset($_POST['modelo_maquina']) && isset($_POST['ip_maquina']) && isset($_POST['comentario'])){

    $empresa = $_POST['empresa'];
    $per_contacto = $_POST['per_contacto'];
    $tel_contacto = $_POST['tel_contacto'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $hor_disp_inicio = $_POST['hor_disp_inicio'];
    $hor_disp_final = $_POST['hor_disp_final'];
    $lunes = $_POST['lunes'];
    $martes = $_POST['martes'];
    $miercoles = $_POST['miercoles'];
    $jueves = $_POST['jueves'];
    $viernes = $_POST['viernes'];
    $numero_serie = $_POST['numero_serie'];
    $modelo_maquina = $_POST['modelo_maquina'];
    $ip_maquina = $_POST['ip_maquina'];
    $comentario = $_POST['comentario'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO tabla(empresa, per_contacto, tel_contacto, email, hor_disp_inicio, hor_disp_final, lunes, martes, miercoles, jueves, viernes,  numero_serie, modelo_maquina, ip_maquina, comentario) values ('$empresa', '$per_contacto', '$tel_contacto', '$email', '$hor_disp_inicio', '$hor_disp_final', '$lunes', '$martes', '$miercoles',  '$jueves', '$viernes', '$numero_serie', '$modelo_maquina', '$ip_maquina', '$comentario')";




    $query = $bdd->prepare( $sql );
    if ($query == false) {
     print_r($bdd->errorInfo());
     die ('Error');
    }
    $sth = $query->execute();
    if ($sth == false) {
     print_r($query->errorInfo());
     die ('Error de ejecucion');


} else { 

 echo "Not found";

  }
}

?>
```

Comment: ¿De dónde sale el objeto `$bdd`?

Comment: Si te fijas en "$con" tienes tu conexión por lo cual... para hacer el "prepare" debes usar la misma variable es decir "$query = $con->prepare( $sql );"..

Comment: mira en los archivos de log de apache (o nginx, o el que uses). Si es un error 500 puede darte informacion al respecto. Publica las ultimas lineas y vemos que podemos interpretar de ello

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes algunas cosillas que cambiar. Primero, has metido la conexión en la variable `$con` pero luego la llamas con `$bdd` que está vacía y no existe como conexión. Por lo que deberías cambiar `$bdd` por `$con`.

Por otro lado, te recomiendo que uses PDO, es mas seguro, te dejo aquí un código, un tanto rápido hecho, así que antes de usarlo verifica.

```
    session_start();

$dbname="nombrebasedatos";
$host="localhost";
$user="root"; //nunca uses el root para estas cosas, crea un user y dale los permisos minimos para funcionar
$pass="pass";
$dsn = "mysql:dbname=$dbname;host=$host;charset=utf8";
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


    if (isset($_POST['empresa']) && isset($_POST['per_contacto']) 
        && isset($_POST['tel_contacto']) && isset($_POST['email']) 
        && isset($_POST['hor_disp_inicio']) && isset($_POST['hor_disp_final']) 
        && isset($_POST['numero_serie']) && isset($_POST['modelo_maquina']) 
        && isset($_POST['ip_maquina']) && isset($_POST['comentario'])){

        $empresa = $_POST['empresa'];
        $per_contacto = $_POST['per_contacto'];
        $tel_contacto = $_POST['tel_contacto'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $hor_disp_inicio = $_POST['hor_disp_inicio'];
        $hor_disp_final = $_POST['hor_disp_final'];
        $lunes = $_POST['lunes'];
        $martes = $_POST['martes'];
        $miercoles = $_POST['miercoles'];
        $jueves = $_POST['jueves'];
        $viernes = $_POST['viernes'];
        $numero_serie = $_POST['numero_serie'];
        $modelo_maquina = $_POST['modelo_maquina'];
        $ip_maquina = $_POST['ip_maquina'];
        $comentario = $_POST['comentario'];
//Lo metemos en un try catch. Si la conexión sale bien, todo funciona.
//Si la conexión sale mal, tira un error, que se mete en $error y lo muestra con  el echo
        try{


        $sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tabla(empresa, per_contacto, tel_contacto, email, hor_disp_inicio, hor_disp_final, numero_serie, modelo_maquina, ip_maquina,comentario) 
            values (:empresa,:percontacto,:telcontacto,:email,:hordispinicio,:hordispfinal,:numeroserie,:modelomaquina,:ipmaquina,:comentario)");

        $sql->execute([
            'empresa'=>$empresa,
            'percontacto'=>$per_contacto,
            'telcontacto'=>$tel_contacto,
            'email'=>$email,
            'hordispinicio'=>$hor_disp_inicio,
            'hordisfinal'=>$hor_disp_final,
            'numeroserie'=>$numero_serie,
            'modelomaquina'=>$modelo_maquina,
            'ipmaquina'=>$ip_maquina,
            'comentario'=>$comentario,
        ]);
            echo "todo bien";
        }catch(PDOException $error){
            echo "no se pudo insertar<br>";
            echo $error;
        }



    }
```

Comment: Buenas, gracias por los cambios que has realizado he visto donde estaba fallando mayormente, acabo de generar unos cambios en el codigo. Ahora si me hace INSERTS, lo unico que no me gusta es que por algun motivo el codigo hace siempre el ELSE.

Comment: porque $sth no lo has definido en ningún lado.